# Regex search multiple suffixes

Tags: python, regex

I have a big list of target words I am searching

```
words = ['Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3']
```

I've been told that a regular expression of this sort:

```
suffix = re.compile('(?:{words}) (\\w+)'.format(words='|'.join(words)))
```

Is pretty efficient, since it fails the regex evaluation immediately when a character that doesn't match the expression is met.

However, the other way around is not efficient:

```
prefix = re.compile('(\\w+) (?:{words})'.format(words='|'.join(words)))
```

Is there an elegant way to instruct python's regex to do the search in reverse ?

### Edit

I've been asked to add example usages:

```
# prefix search
title = re.compile('(?:Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.|Dr. |Lt.) (\\w+)')
# suffix search
company = re.compile('(\\w+) (?:Inc.| LLP.|ltd.|GMBH)')
# invoking the regex
all_people_names  = title.findall(document)
all_company_names = company.findall(document)
```

### Edit 2

A lot of people had been skeptical regarding the significance of the timing differences.

I've implemented the 2 methods: `endswith()` and `endswith_rev()` that reverses the string and the results as kabanus suggested.

These are the results:

[image: Timing]

As you can see, it makes a **huge** difference, even with a small amount of suffixes.

Comment: Why not use `(?:{words}$)`

Comment: Doesn't `$` match the end of the string ?

Comment: Can you add more detail to the question, an example possibly of what you're trying to match etc.

Comment: Furthermore the above is usually not terribly inefficient. The performance boost is mainly due to the fact that a regular expression *can* use dynamic programming to check multiple substrings at once.

Comment: @UriGoren: no, the `$` is the anchor of the end of the string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, the `$` anchor doesn't help much, for example for the text `'google inc is nice, but apple inc is nicer'`, I want `re.findall` to return `['google', 'apple']`. If I use the `$` directive, then it forces the expression to appear at the end of the search string, thus returning `[]`.

Comment: Oh wow, impressive, good optimization question, I guess regex really isn't that smart under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the way you did it you have to test all the possible prefixes up to the suffix. One way to beat this, only if the string is long enough, is to reverse everything, so you get back to your first example:

```
prefix = re.compile('(?:{words}) (\\w+)'.format(words='|'.join([word[::-1] for word in words])))
re.match(prefix,mystring[::-1])
```

so you are searching from the end, and get back the same pattern - remember to reverse the matches though. <strike>I wonder how long does the list of words and string need to be to make this worth it.</strike> Apparently this is a major optimization booster see OP for some timing.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my question with the timings, it's pretty interesting

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular Expression is OK in some cases, or required in others, e.g. when you configure a system that allows you to match patterns and the input type is a RegEx pattern, but for this simple use case RegEx just wastes CPU cycles.

This use case is simple because you know the position at which you want to match the subbstrings - they are always at the end of the input, so each `suffix` either matches the given `inputString` or not:

```
inputString[ len(inputString) - len(suffix) : ] == suffix
```

But of course, you already have the Python method `endswith(suffix)`, so you can test with:

```
inputString.endswith( suffix )
```

The `suffix` argument can be a `tuple` though, so you can do the following:

```
suffixes = ( "Inc.", "inc.", "Gmbh", "ltd.", "LTD", "LLP" )
inputString.endswith( suffixes )
```

Or for a case insensitive search:

```
suffixes = ( "inc.", "gmbh", "ltd.", "llp" )
inputString.lower().endswith( suffixes )
```

Anyway, if performance is really important then perhaps Python is not the best language.

Comment: I am looking for a `findall` functionality and not a `match` functionality, so the `endswith` does not help that much.

Comment: @UriGoren So if it matches you add it to the result, or am I missing something? What kind of values does "document" have in your example? Is it simply a single phrase, e.g. a name or a name of a company, or is it a complex document that needs to be parsed? I'm really interested to see the performance difference between RegEx and other solutions. Is it possible for you to post somewhere your test case?

Answer (score 0):

try
`.*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)`

will match

```
1.jpg
b.png
c.gif
```

test it in https://regex101.com/

```
Non-capturing group (?:jpg|gif|png)
1st Alternative jpg
jpg matches the characters jpg literally (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative gif
gif matches the characters gif literally (case sensitive)
3rd Alternative png
png matches the characters png literally (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags 
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

Comment: Note that the question is regarding performance, not correctness.
Searching for multiple suffices in a single regex is very inefficient on large texts due to the linear way the algorithm works.
Reversing the string and the pattern is the way to go when dealing with suffixes.